# What classes need to 'Use' the Enterprise Application Block's dll's?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, enterprise-library

I'm adding the the Microsoft Enterprise Application Block's "Exception Handling" module to my project. Following thier instructions mnsd [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649728.aspx) it says I need to add a `using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling;` statement. Does this need to go in every single file that throws an exception handled by the the block, or just the file that catches the error?

For example, say I've got FormMainView, FormMainPresenter, and Class1, Class2, Class3. FormMainView is the view that calls FormMainPresenter, and that delegates specific tasks to the three classes. Classes 1 -3 throw various exceptions and they're caught in the Presenter. Do all 4 files need this using statement, or just the presenter?

Using the MS EAB 4.1, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `using` statement needs to be in all .cs files that make use of the `Exception`. Both classes that throw the exceptions and classes that handle the thrown exceptions.

Visual studio will complain when you are missing a using. To double-check your usings you can remove one and see if the compiler complains, if it does then the using is required. If it doesn't complain then the using was redundant.

> FormMainView is the view that calls FormMainPresenter, and that
>   delegates specific tasks to the three classes.
>
> Classes 1 -3 throw
>   various exceptions and they're caught in the Presenter.
>
> Do all 4 files
>   need this using statement, or just the presenter?

If Exceptions are caught in `FormMainPresenter`, `FormMainView` will not need to know about them so no using is required in `FormMainPresenter`. A using in the other 4 classes is required.

Comment: In regards to your second paragraph, perhaps I misunderstand how the Exception Handling block works. Say I simply threw a File Not Found exception while using System.IO. That'd compile perfectly fine. Now say my Exception block had a policy for File Not Found exceptions... Wouldn't it still compile just fine, but not behave as I'd expect it to? Still in the process of configuring my App file and reading MSDN so I can't easily test it.

I guess a better response is that it simply says "Use a `Using` statement instead of fully qualifiying it", so I wasn't sure where I'd be "addressing" the block